# Physics on/off issues

Tags: physics, keyframes

I'm a beginner with blender (~50 hours of experience but not much skill), and the physics is causing me some deep troubles. My scene contains 2 objects, and I want one to fall onto the other (not using physics), clip through slightly, snap back up and then simulate physics (this will make it seems as if there is lag). However I cannot get this to work for the life of me, so I will describe what I have done.

At frame 1, I create a keyframe with the location of the falling object (3z, 0x, 0y), and in the settings section of the rigid body section, I tick "animation" and untick "dynamic" (making sure they are included in the keyframe settings).

On frame 58, I add a keyframe where the only change is the object is now at 0.4z, 0x, 0y, and clipping inside of the object at (0z, 0x, 0y). This works as intended, the object smoothly falls into it (although there must be some collision, since after clipping inside, it starts to slow down via some mechanic I do not understand).

On frame 65, I add a keyframe where the falling object is back at (2z, 0x, 0y), and in the rigid body settings, tick the "dynamic" box and untick the "animation" box. This keyframe does cause headaches, if I do not uncheck the "animation" box the object will not undergo any physics, ever.

However, on frame 66, things break down. There are no more keyframes after frame 65. The falling object will do a variety of undesirable things, but the most common are:

1. It will snap to (-10z, 0x, 0y) and start falling slowly (gravity is still normal but what I mean is that the object has an initial downward velocity of 0). If I try to move the object at this point, it instantly snaps back to the undesired position.
2. It will become invisible for no aparrent reason.
3. Blender will crash

I am on Blender 2.90.1. Anyone know what is going on here? I've heard that changing the "dynamic" setting is like not the way you are supposed to enable and disable physics, but I cannot find any other way. I have also experimented with starting the physics simulation 1 frame after I move the object up to (2z, 0x, 0y,) to no avail. Help would be greatly appreciated, and does not specifically have to relate to using this method, I have heard there are other methods which can achieve the same effect I am after but don't know what they are.

Edit: It seems I had changed a few things, since I cant replicate the crashes or the object having physics after I put it back at (2z, 0x, 0y), but any combination of "animation" and "dynamic" checkboxes will not let physics resume.

Comment: hello, could you please describe succinctly what you want to do? Do you mean it is going down, up, then fall with physics? I'm not sure that the Dynamic option is useful...

Comment: Yes, it is going down, then up, and then falling with physics. I have also attempted to use separate objects, but i still need to store one object away (use a keyframe for the storage position, then another for the position it assumes after the 1st object is done), and i have to leave physics on the whole time or i will have the same issue above, but if i leave it on the whole time it refuses to follow my keyframes. ie i tell it to go to (3z, 0x, 0y) after falling about 50 metres off camera, but it refuses to do it and it continues falling as if there is no keyframe.

Comment: Doubtless Moonboots is going to come up with something positively brilliant.
In the meantime you might find this also helpful.  It's how I've been coping with your physics switching problem.  It also cures a host of parentage switching as well.  It's basic but it does work.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189665/animating-active-object-in-physics-simulation/190246#190246

Comment: @Rubiksmath , did you get this working?