# Incrementing bake animation with physics

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I made a animation where I rotate a gameboard to move a ball: https://youtu.be/-C43MW5vzy8

[image]

The ball is active and the board a passive rigid body that's animated, rotation only.

Moving the ball ahead on the board was a slow process, because everytime I changed one keyframe on the end, I had to rerun the animation again from the start.

I want to solve the puzzle bit by bit by storing the animation for every part where the ball ends up in the right place, and then continue trying rotations from there. Is this possible?

Edit: I managed to bake the ball animation to keyframes, to a certain halfway keyframe for example. But once I do that, the rigid body is removed for the ball.. Do I have to keep re-adding the physics every time I bake a certain keyframe range?

Also, I'm confused as what I have to do with any cache settings. If I press 'delete bake' it keeps saying there's frames in memory. Should I even use any of these options, like 'update all to frame' or 'calculate to frame'?

Comment: Oli, the short answer is YES, you can do it that way and it's not difficult.  Here is an example of incremental bakes -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189665/animating-active-object-in-physics-simulation/190246#190246 

An alternative might be to switch between physics and following that path you've drawn on the board.  Use physics to drop it into holes, then back to animation to get it back to the surface before resuming path following. The speed around each section of the path can be varied to suit. You'd animate the board tilts to suit whatever the ball is doing.

Comment: @Edgel3D cool example, I'll try out the baking-in-steps

Answer (score 0):

If you are an experienced video gamer with good reactions, you could do it in "one" shot like this:

I used here just a plane (physics: passive, checked animated) and a sphere (rigid body active).

Then activate autokeying [image]

and start your animation by pressing spacebar.

You can grab your plane and move/rotate it during your animation, it works!

At the end you have a "ready" animation. But yes, you have to have quick reactions.

You might want to build some helper rigs/empties to make the movement/rotation of the plane easier.

[image]

Comment: This might be a fun solution but I'm afraid that's not what I'm really looking for..I mean, what if the next board I design has 100 holes instead of 19? Nice outside the box thinking though, I'll give it a shot :)