# Object resets to position of deleted Keyframe

Tags: keyframes

I have a hand Model that I parented to a cylinder so it looks like a hand spear.
The plan was for the Spear to move in time to hit a rolling brick ball away from a Spider Robot's way, simple and straight to the point.
I have everything up and ready except the Spear, as this is the second time it happens to me in this project alone, I set a beginning location Keyframe and then in frame 350 I set another location Keyframe in a different location. I wanted to do it again as I made a mistake with my calculations so I deleted the Keyframes, I am supposed to be able to move the spear normally now but no, whenever I move it It just resets to the location in which I put the now deleted first keyframe. It happened many times before and I usually just delete the Object and do it again but this is starting to get on my nerves XD.
The location settings are not locked I checked many times.
I just don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: The spear parent can't do that on it's own.  Could you have left a keyframe say at frame 1, 0, or somewhere else along the timeline that's pulling it back?  Check the Dopesheet. Hit the "Home" key to make sure all keyframes are included.  If it's not a forgotten keyframe, are there redundant strips in there.  (they're usually underlined in red)


Is the cylinder/spear in fact parented to something else?  It may be that a forgotten constraint, modifier, physics or whatever, is acting on it.  Check the sphere's constraints list, then modifier list, then it's physics properties.

Comment: Continued - You might try saving then exiting Blender completely,  loading it back in again.

Comment: saving then exiting Blender completely, loading it back in again did the trick, however I still don't know what I did wrong. There is nothing in the constraints list or the modifier list but It does have Rigid Body in physics properties, But I kept that at default. Only thing I changed was Friction. There are no KeyFrames left or any redundant strips either. This is giving me a headache XD. –

Comment: Your Rigid Body physics could well be the problem.  The physics engine doesn't necessarily reset or update everything when you change settings or even remove the physics altogether! The object can continue to behave as before and even go erratic sometimes.  Only a complete save, exit, and reload will rid the object of the former settings.  Cont...

Comment: ...Cont - It's one of the reasons I find baking an object's behavior, once I get it right can save hours of headache work later down the track.  You are then free to clear it of physics and other constraints, regain full control again and continue unhindered with the project's next sequence.  Example -

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189665/animating-active-object-in-physics-simulation/190246#190246